# checking if a method exists or can be called in twig

Tags: php, html, twig

If inside a twig I have an object that I wanted to be tested if a method called getName can be called on that object, is there such case?

I tried doing the following without any success:

```
 {% if lastCategory.method(getName) is defined  %}
```

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can do it this way :

```
{{ attribute(object, method) is defined ? 'Method exists' : 'Method does not exist' }}
```

In your case, it will be something like

```
{{ attribute(lastCategory, 'getName') is defined ? 'Method exists' : 'Method does not exist' }}
```

See the [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html)

Comment: for some reason I am getting Variable "getName" does not exist in ...... when doing that

Comment: Try to replace the `getName` var directly by one of correponding value to see if the rest of the code will works...

Comment: Better use `{{ attribute(lastCategory, 'getNAme') is defined ? [...] }}` isn't it ?

Comment: Not sure, what i understood , is that `getName` is a var that contain the name of the method we are looking for... not the name directly! adit should have the answer.

Comment: That not helped me. Only write Twig extension helped me

Comment: {{ attribute(_self, 'getNAme') is defined ? [...] }}  to check in current scope

Answer (score 1):

This is not really something you should be doing in a Twig template. Note that Twig will never throw an error if you try to access something that does not exist. `foo.bar` is a Twig expression that translates into something much more complex than `$foo->bar()`. Your template should look like this:

```
{{ lastCategory.name }}
```

This covers virtually all grounds:

- `lastCategory` is an array and `name` is an index
- `lastCategory` is an object and

  - `name` is a property
  - `name` is a method
  - `getName` is a method
  - `isName` is a method
- none of the above, in which case nothing is output

Even `foo.bar.this.does.not.exist` will never ever throw an error, it will simply do nothing.
If you *need* to test, simply do:

```
{% if lastCategory.name %}
```

If you want to avoid calling the method twice (though that'd be bad object design):

```
{% set name = lastCategory.name %}
{% if name %}
```

Or maybe you're looking for this idiom:

```
{{ lastCategory.name|default('No name') }}
```

Comment: This is wrong. I get an uncaught exception `'Twig_Error_Runtime' with message 'Neither the property "foo" nor one of the methods "foo()", "getfoo()"/"isfoo()" or "__call()" exist and have public access`

Comment: Well, what *do* you have on your object that you're trying to get…?

Comment: Sometimes my object has a foo() method and sometimes it doesn't have one. The twig template is a general purpose one that can be given many different types of objects.

Comment: "This is wrong. I get an uncaught exception" This exception is caught by the `|default('No name')` tag.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. I was looking for exactly this with automated detection of non-existing methods in twig. Your answer filled many future gaps that I would have to struggle with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  `{% if lastCategory.name is defined  %}`. It worked

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Just create Twig Extension and use in your template `{% if method_exists(lastCategory, 'getName') %}Yes{% else %}No{% endif %}`

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Twig;

class SomeTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension {

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            'method_exists' => new \Twig_SimpleFunction('method_exists', array($this, 'isMethodExist'))
        );
    }

    public function isMethodExist($object, $method)
    {
        return method_exists($object, $method);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'method_exists_twig_extension';
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51553457/8162442) as basis but instead `return method_exists($object, $method);` I used `return isset($object->$method);` such as 1st variant always returned false for unknown reasons.